# How can I update seats array for a particular movie time using mongoose in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, nested, movie

The Json that I am using. I want to get hold of seats array for movie name Avengers and movie time is 7:30 pm.

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5adc21bd19398524589381a9"
},
"screens": [
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5adc21bd19398524589381ad"
        },
        "movieName": "Avengers",
        "movieTimings": [
            {
                "seats": [
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5adc21bd19398524589381af"
                },
                "movieTime": "7:30 pm"
            },
            {
                "seats": [
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5adc21bd19398524589381ae"
                },
                "movieTime": "8:30 pm"
            }
        ],
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more? What do you mean by "get hold of seats"?

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you the seats array for all screens having `movieTime` as "7:30 pm":

I have assumed that the main object is called movie.

```
movie.screens.map(function(scr){ //goes through the movie.screens array
    return scr.movieTimings.filter(function(timing){ 
            return timing.movieTime == "7:30 pm"; //for each screen object, returns only those that have their movieTime as 7:30 pm 
        })
        .map(function(item){
            return item.seats; // returns the seats array from the filtered screens
        })
})
```

Hope this helps!